# Material UI Searchbox mixed w Autocomplete with react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have an AppBar component (provided by Material UI), I want my Searchbox field to act just as it acts in:

https://material-ui.com/.

As you can see there, it's sort of a mixture of Searchbox and Autocomplete - by view it looks like a Searchbox but after inputing a value - it returns set of selectable options (Autocomplete effect).

Material UI docs gives the following component
for the Searchbar I wish to use:

https://material-ui.com/components/app-bar/#app-bar-with-a-primary-search-field

And for Autocomplete:

https://material-ui.com/components/autocomplete/

What would you guys suggest to get this result, same as their?

Answer (score 2):

I chose the [Material UI Customized Autocomplete](https://material-ui.com/components/autocomplete/#customized-autocomplete) and [AppBar with search field](https://material-ui.com/components/app-bar/#app-bar-with-search-field)
I have create mixed them together and created a small example for you [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-rjw8z?file=/try.js).

The main idea here is to connect **Popper** with any element you want.

Hope I helped you. Please feel free to ask more questions :)